# How to Databind through C# and not WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So i'm using WPF the wrong way and i have a bunch of dynamically created objects on load... i'm trying to figure out how to databind through C#... what would be the equivalent C# code to this:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedGame}">
    <Label Content="{Binding HomeScoreText}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding AwayScoreText}" />
</StackPanel>
```

i'm having trouble finding examples of this online.. thanks

Comment: Is the template itself dynamic, or just the number of items and the data bound to them?  If the latter, just create a new user control so that the template is static, and then dynamically create instances of that user control and bind data to that.  That's at least...less bad.

Comment: only thing created in WPF is a TabControl.  then the grid inside each tabitem and the stackpanel/labels are created dynamically on load as it reads data from SQL

Comment: still confused unfortunately bleh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has a sample page demonstrating how to [Create a Binding In Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx).

In your case, you could do the above via:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
Label label1 = new Label();
Label label2 = new Label();

panel.Children.Add(label1);
panel.Children.Add(label2);

var yourVM = GetYourCurrentViewModelWithSelectedGameProperty();

// Set data context
Binding binding = new Binding("SelectedGame");
binding.Source = yourVM;
panel.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, binding);

binding = new Binding("HomeScoreText");
binding.Source = panel.DataContext;
label1.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);

binding = new Binding("AwayScoreText");
binding.Source = panel.DataContext;
label2.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
```

Comment: what would i put for here: "GetYourCurrentViewModelWithSelectedGameProperty();"?  that's the only thing i dont understand.  ty!

Comment: @user1189352 You wanted to bind the data context to `SelectedGame` - you need to set the Source to the object that contains the SelectedGame property.  That's typically your ViewModel layer, hence that naming.